# A free program to turn a PC into a Chromecast or AirPlay receiver

Tags: windows, gratis, video, ios, streaming

Most iPhone apps only allow you to cast a streaming video to another device via Chromecast or via AirPlay. But I would like to cast to my Windows 10 PC (for watching Hulu Live TV on a PC, as I discuss in [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/q/1226910/276056)).

Are there any free programs which turn your PC into either a Chromecast receiver or an AirPlay receiver?

I know of two paid programs, [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) and [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/), but I want a free one.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cast for Education](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast-for-education/bnmgbcehmiinmmlmepibeeflglhbhlea) is a free Chrome extension that turns your PC into a (limited) Chromecast.

The page says you need a G Suite for Education account, but you don't. The extension will tell you that without a GSE account, anyone (on your network I presume) will be able to cast to the device, but that's fine for a home setting.

The app won't cast everything though. I was able to cast a Chrome tab (YouTube) from my Windows PC to my Linux laptop, but I wasn't able to cast a YouTube video from Android, or Google Play Music from Android.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: The Google Cast for Education receiver is not a generic Chromecast Receiver. Indeed, it only receives casts from Chrome PC browsers.

Comment: This is no longer supported. Link is dead and the project has been discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could use the [Styled Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver#styled_media_receiver) that you can download from the Cast Application Framework once you [register a new application](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration).

Comment: Any guide on setting it up? I was able to create an publish an SMR, and I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't have experience with it myself, I just found that link from searching.

Comment: This is not relevant.  The Styled Media Receiver is what runs on the actual Chromecast device itself.  It doesn't work without the hardware.