# Is there any (paid) software that can receive Google cast from video streaming apps (such as Netflix)?

Tags: osx, server, chromecast

Many mobile video apps have a "Cast" option (e.g. [Netflix](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/49)) built-in, which allows them to stream the video to a Google Chromecast.

I am looking for software that could function as a Cast receiver, specifically for apps like Netflix. Preferably the software works on a Mac device, but a Windows or Linux option is fine as well.

It's not a hard requirement that this software can receive the Google Cast protocol, it's just that I don't want to ask users to download another app to show videos on the screen.

#### What I've found so far

- I am familiar with [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/mac), but it specifically [does not support these streaming apps](https://support.airserver.com/support/solutions/articles/43000512407-some-streaming-apps-such-as-netflix-hulu-apple-tv-disney-hbo-do-not-work-with-airserver).
- I found [this previous question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/43419/1805), but both answers only covered part of the question and are now outdated.
- I am aware that [Kodi](https://cormang.com/2018/06/30/how-to-stream-or-cast-from-android-to-kodi/) has functionality available that allows it to receive streams. However, you need a special client app for that and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Unless you cast the whole screen Chromecast you gets the streaming URL and further details like authentication cookies. Chromecast the directly requests the video and plays it. The "casting" device then just acts as remote control for play/pause, volume control and so on. So the cast target needs to be supported by the streaming service e.g. regarding content protection (DRM).

Comment: Yes, I sort of got that idea. But is there no software that emulates what Chromecast does, including the DRM? I'm fine with paying for it, but I just don't want to send over any info to the seller of the cast device (Google, amazon, etc...)